# How to calculate the local volatilty surface using QuantLib?

Tags: quantlib

I'd like to calculate the local volatility surface for a series of option strikes, similar to the surface described in this paper:

http://www.ederman.com/new/docs/gs-local_volatility_surface.pdf

This is the image I am referring to in the aforementioned paper:

[image]

I know QuantLib has the ability to do this - but does anyone know the correct C# function call(s)?

I'm using the C# build of QuantLib, from:
http://www.resolversystems.com/products/quantlib-binary/

Comment: I am not saying that your question is off-topic here, but please note that there's also http://quant.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Good point. I've posted the question on this site as well.

Comment: See http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/1195/how-to-calculate-the-local-volatility-surface-using-quantlib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer quoted from QuantLib:

> Assuming you're referring to the local-volatility class implemented in
>   `<QuantLib/ql/termstructures/volatility/equityfx/localvolsurface.hpp>`,
>   it's among the several classes that are not exported through SWIG. 
>   You'll have to add it to the SWIG interface files (probably in
>   `volatilities.i`), regenerate the wrappers and recompile them.  If you
>   need instructions on the building process, you can ask on the QuantLib
>   mailing list.

Answer (score -5):

Quantlib is not free.

I tried:

-EPPlus, which support plotting chart on Excel, but only no surface chart

-NPOI, doesn't support any charts